# How can I navigate my scene FPS style similar to how Unity does?

Tags: workflow, 3d-view

I am aware of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> fly, but it's extremely cumbersome having to use the scroll wheel to change the velocity of flight and moving the mouse from the center to spin.

Is there a way to move the viewport camera (not the scene camera) like Unity lets you right click and fly around with WASD and moving the mouse?

Comment: You're a FPS gamer, aren't you ? :P You should try a 3D mouse... It's really better than Fly mode :)

Comment: Yep, and also a hobby Unity developer. It's unimaginably useful to fly around the scene at times, instead of orbiting around a point like Blender does. And I don't have or plan to get a 3D mouse.

Comment: If somebody is to write a script for this, I suggest that it should be triggered by holding Shift and right clicking. Then dragging while right clicking should turn the view, and WASD moves.

Comment: @Keavon well, the problem is that you'd have to move the existing wasd hotkeys out of the way. I (and I assume many blender users) use 'w' and 'a' very often. edit: nvm I'm stupid, you'd probably just use a modal mode like in fly mode

Comment: That's why I said holding Shift and RMB would be required to activate it.

Comment: I thought `WASD` did control velocity and hight in Fly mode? (maybe I don't understand how you want it to behave.)

Comment: Mouse movement directly should control the viewport camera (so moving to the left 1 cm on your desktop should rotate the camera an exact number of degrees exactly when the camera moves). Pushing W should move at a constant speed exactly during the duration of holding it. Essentially how a first person shooter's controls work (mouse to turn the screen, w to walk forward, a to strafe left, etc.)

Comment: Shift RMB, like in selecting additional stuff?

Comment: Touché. Okay, perhaps hold space to navigate, and make the spacebar search menu activate on spacebar up so this doesn't trigger it if done in combination with a right click.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The latest version of Blender has *Walk Mode*, You can access it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> (the tilde/backtick key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) or *View > Navigation > Walk Navigation*. If you want to use *Fly Mode* (which used to be the default), you can switch between them in *User Preferences > Input*.

Under 2.8+ you can access both from the *3D View* header menu *View > Navigate > Walk* or *Fly*:

[image]

It's <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> just like in FPS-games, <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> to move up/down. <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> enable gravity and collision, and <kbd>V</kbd> to jump in gravity mode. <kbd>Space</kbd> teleports you to the surface you are pointed at. You can even change the key-bindings to enable FPS Walk (the official name) on <kbd>MMB</kbd> down, and confirm on <kbd>MMB</kbd> up to always rotate (or rather: look) in FPS-style - or even hold <kbd>MMB</kbd> down and use <kbd>WASD</kbd>!

Comment: Wow, very impressive. Almost like a built-in FPS controller. I look forward to that, but FPS walking still isn't FPS flying which would be a very useful addition to that feature too.

Comment: @Keavon: it's both - with gravity off, it's FPS-style flying (`/noclip`, or rather `/ufo` since up/down uses the global Z axis), with gravity on it's FPS-style walking. `A` and `D` are for strafing, `W` and `S` to move forward / backward. With gravity off, `W` and `S` may change your view height based on the view direction (move along the forward vector of the player), whereas your vertical location is based on the environment with gravity on for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the FPS Fly addon:
http://www.ewocprojects.be/fpsfly.html

A FPS-style viewport navigation was a proposed project for the steam workshop devs, so not sure if there will be a C-implementation of the above addon.

Comment: The new version had a bug and the old version is really sluggish (it refreshes the view at a low FPS and the general controls are unsatisfactory). Thanks for the link, nonetheless. It may come in handy at times, even with its problems. What did you say about the Steam Workshop? How does that have to do with Blender? And what about a C-implementation? I thought scripts are written in Python for Blender.

Comment: @Keavon some Valve guys wrote an email to the Blender developer mailing list asking around for interest in collaborating with them (specifically workshop integration, i.e. publishing workshop items directly from within Blender) and the possibility of offering a download of Blender through Steam. I don't understand how WASD navigation would benefit from being a core C system instead of a python plugin though.

Comment: It would run smoother? See the Fly Navigation code, there's smoothing to the mouse input and it's not sluggerish at all. And as there's nothing like Blender plugins, it would pretty much mean that there will always be official support for the feature. Proposals for the steam workshop devs: [Google Docs Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuS_F0ZKX-zTdGxKOEMtRmI2Tno4UUlPZzVfNXB6RHc#gid=0)