# Is it possible to nagivate Blender viewport like with WASD in a video game?

Tags: 3d-view

In video games, flying in the level is typically like this:

- <kbd>W</kbd> - move forward;
- <kbd>S</kbd> - move backward;
- <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> - move right/left without turning;
- <kbd>Space</kbd> - jump/ascend;

If I try this in Blender, it does not work (and in general makes some mysterious hard-to-undo changes when I press unknown keys).

- Is there any easy mode for navigating the scene using video-game-like controls?
- Is there even mode video-gamish mode with gravity (towards the center of the closest big object) and clipping (not allowing point of view to become too close to some surfase)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the Walk and Fly navigation tools (shown in the image).  Walk, in particular, allows you to temporarily navigate using the WASD combination
[image]

Answer (score 15):

The shortcut is now <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>, for `2.79` use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>. Then you can use <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: in blender 2.8 the shortcut is SHIFT `

Comment: You can map this to a mouse button to make it more like other 3D software: I've answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187570/101687