# Camera stacking

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Sometimes I have to zoom hard to get in and out of an area. Is there a way to prevent viewport camera from stacking in objects while zooming? Or is there a way to move the camera like in UE4?

Comment: [What's the quickest, easiest way to point the camera somewhere in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/43/)

Comment: [Is there a better way to move around and view a big scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13555/is-there-a-better-way-to-move-around-and-view-a-big-scene)

Comment: [Is it possible to nagivate Blender viewport like with WASD in a video game?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13636/31447)