# Having trouble making a keymap work when mouse button is released

Tags: shortcut, customization, navigation

I'm trying to bind `view3d.navigate` to <kbd>middle mouse button</kbd> so that it's only activated while the buttons is pressed.

I'm having trouble getting it to deactivate. I've tried every option "click", "press", "click drag" for example:

[image]

I presumed that didn't work because it needed a command to run on release which would deactivate `view3d.navigate`. I tried `view3d.select` as seen below but still no luck:
[image]

Any hints on what i should try?

Why am I doing this? I'm trying to replicate other 3D design programs. `view3d.navigate` allows navigating the viewport with <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> keys and moving the mouse.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it said 'Walk/Fly' in the screenshot - didn't realise Fly mode's generic name was 'navigate'. Will delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Go *Preferences* and see *Keymap*.

*3D View > 3D View (Global) > View Navigation (Walk/Fly)*

set to *Mouse* , *Middle Mouse* , *Press* (or *Click Drag*)

then

*3D View > View3D Walk Modal > Confirm*

set to *Mouse* , *Middle Mouse* , *Release*